# How to create script interpreter with Boost C++

Tags: c++, boost

So... Are there any standard libs in boost for creating some scripts/xmls readers that would map that script into objects via some rool?

Comment: my main point - I have lots of classes that started up in difrent order will generate different results. I need something to make tham start in desired order. after app was compiled.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, but maybe this is what you are looking for http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/property_tree.html

Comment: your question seems a bit confused; I'm not at all sure what you want here. Can you try giving a more concrete example? By the way, you can click the 'edit' link below your question to add more details; this can be better than comments, as comments will be hidden if there are too many of them

Comment: I'm not sure what “starting up a class” is supposed to mean, but I guess your code relies on the order of initializations of global objects in different compilation units? I believe http://gotw.ca/ has some articles on that topic; short answer: Don't use globals; if you (think you) have to, use global `autoptr` s and initialize them in `main` or some function called from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your classes to start up in a particular order, I think a script language is over-kill.  What you need is a topographical sort.

**What You Need**

Boost has a [topographical sort](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/graph/doc/topological_sort.html).  You can also read up on a very-readable C# implementation that should be easy for you to move over to C++, if the boost library is a bit much for you.  That can be found [here](http://tawani.blogspot.com/2009/02/topological-sorting-and-cyclic.html).

**What it does**

Basically, you provide the sorting algorithm with your classes and then you add their dependencies (the sort algorithm views these as vertices and edges).  Once you're done, you apply the algorithm.  What you get out is what objects depend on what.

I've used this exact method when I had a bunch of subsystems that needed to be loaded, some of which relied on others, some didn't.  The amount of subsystems was arbitrary and due to the plugin nature of the program, unknown at compile time.

I assigned each subsystem a unique identifier (incidentally, using `boost::uuid`), and each subsystem listed the identifiers of other subsystems which relied on it.  This was fed to the sorter and my initialization order came out the back end.

To help you on your way, here's some code (NOTE:  At this point, I did not know that the boost library existed, this is my own implementation based on the C# code from the link I provided above.)

```
        // class TopologicalSorter
        template<typename TYPE> class TopologicalSorter
        {
        private:

            std::vector<TYPE>               m_Vertices;
            std::vector<std::vector<TYPE> > m_Matrix;
            std::vector<TYPE>               m_Sorted;
            TYPE                            m_nNumVerts;
            TYPE                            m_nSize;

            // private helpers
            int noSuccessors()
            {
                bool isEdge;
                for(TYPE row(0); row < m_nNumVerts; row++)
                {
                    isEdge = false;
                    for(TYPE col(0); col < m_nNumVerts; col++)
                    {
                        if(m_Matrix[row][col] > 0)  // edge to another?
                        {
                            isEdge = true;
                            break;
                        };
                    };

                    if(!isEdge)
                        return(row);
                };

                return(-1); // nope!
            };  // eo noSuccessors

            void deleteVertex(TYPE _vertex)
            {
                if(_vertex != m_nNumVerts - 1)
                {
                    for(TYPE j(_vertex); j < m_nNumVerts - 1; j++)
                        m_Vertices[j] = m_Vertices[j + 1];

                    for(TYPE row(_vertex); row < m_nNumVerts - 1; row++)
                        moveRowUp(row, m_nNumVerts);

                    for(TYPE col(_vertex); col < m_nNumVerts - 1; col++)
                        moveColLeft(col, m_nNumVerts - 1);
                };

                --m_nNumVerts;
            };  // eo deleteVertex

            void moveRowUp(TYPE _row, TYPE _length)
            {
                for(TYPE col(0); col < _length; col++)
                    m_Matrix[_row][col] = m_Matrix[_row + 1][col];
            };  // eo moveRowUp

            void moveColLeft(TYPE _col, TYPE _length)
            {
                for(TYPE row(0); row < _length; row++)
                    m_Matrix[row][ _col] = m_Matrix[row][_col + 1];
            };  // eo moveColLeft

        public:
            TopologicalSorter(TYPE _size) : m_nNumVerts(0)
                                          , m_Vertices(_size)
                                          , m_Matrix(_size)
                                          , m_Sorted(_size)
                                          , m_nSize(_size)
            {
                assert(_size > 0);
                for(TYPE i(0); i < m_nSize; ++i)
                {
                    for(TYPE j(0); j < m_nSize; ++j)
                        m_Matrix[i].push_back(0);
                };
            };  // eo ctor


            ~TopologicalSorter(){};


            // public methods


            TYPE addVertex(TYPE _vertex)
            {
                m_Vertices[m_nNumVerts++] = _vertex;
                return(m_nNumVerts - 1);
            };  // eo addVertex

            void addEdge(TYPE _start, TYPE _end)
            {
                m_Matrix[_start][_end] = 1;
            };  // eo addEdge

            std::vector<TYPE> sort()
            {
                int currVertex;
                while(m_nNumVerts)
                {
                    currVertex = noSuccessors();
                    coreAssert(currVertex != -1, "Graph has cycles");

                    m_Sorted[m_nNumVerts - 1] = m_Vertices[currVertex];
                    deleteVertex(currVertex);
                };  // eo while(m_nNumVerts)

                return(std::move(m_Sorted));
            };  // eo sort

        };  // eo class TopologicalSorter
```

Now, this is how this was used with loading and initializing the subsystems (Uuid is just a `typedef` for `boost::uuids::uuid`)

```
    // create a topological sorter:
    utility::TopologicalSorter<ManagerVector_sz> sorter(m_Managers.size());
    std::map<Uuid, ManagerVector_sz> indexes;

    // add vertices and edges
    for(ManagerVector_sz i(0); i < m_Managers.size(); ++i)
        indexes.insert(std::pair<Uuid, ManagerVector_sz>(m_Managers[i]->getUuid(), sorter.addVertex(i)));

    for(ManagerVector_sz i(0); i < m_Managers.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(m_Managers[i]->getDependencies().size())
        {
            for(ManagerVector_sz j(0); j < m_Managers[i]->getDependencies().size(); ++j)
                sorter.addEdge(i, indexes[m_Managers[i]->getDependencies()[j]]);
        };
    };

    // get the order in which we should initialise
    m_SortedIndexes = sorter.sort();

    // and initialise
    ManagerVector* mv(&m_Managers);
    std::for_each(m_SortedIndexes.rbegin(),
                  m_SortedIndexes.rend(),
                  [&mv](int i){mv->at(i)->initialise();});
```

Hope this helps and avoid an un-necessary script!

Answer (score 2):

The [Boost Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) library should allow you to define a configuration format fairly easily.